# How to get the simulation method used by AerSimulator(method='automatic')?

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

Is it possible to obtain the simulation method by a simulation run when using `AerSimulator(method='automatic')`?

For example running a circuit:

```
simulation_run = AerSimulator(method='automatic').run(qc)
```

Then trying to obtain the simulation method used by the two methods:

```
simulation_run.backend().configuration().backend_name
simulation_run.backend().options.method
```

This will only output 'automatic' but I would like to know what method the simulator actually used during the simulation run, e.g. 'statevector', 'density_matrix', 'stabilizer', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method is reported in metadata in the `ExperimentResult`. So, you can get it using the below code snippet:

```
simulation_run.result().results[0].metadata['method']
```